# Parental control in Connectify Hotspot

Tags: windows-7, parental-controls, connectify

I am sharing my ethernet connexion over WiFi using Connectify Hotspot, and I am searching a way to ban access to adult content for all devices that are connected to my hotspot without "physical" access to these devices in preference by redirecting them to a another website to alert them (a page I created in local network).
I am running Windows 7 SP1 and Connectify Hotspot 3.7.1.25486.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been trying to figure out ways to implement a similar functionality into our software DigiParent for some time now. While figuring out the simplest and best way to implement what we wanted we stumbled upon a software titled OPENDNS that can accomplish most of what you want. You might want to check it out at: http://www.opendns.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, this wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it helped :)